# Do-Catch and overflow

Tags: swift, do-catch

How I can wrap in `do` `catch` overflow error

```
    let increasePerSecond: UInt32 = UInt32.max 
    let offset: UInt32
    do {
        offset = try ((nowTimeInterval - calculatedTimeInterval) * increasePerInterval)
    } catch _ {
        offset = 0
    }
```

But if I have error  in `do` section I do not get in `catch` and have crash my app

**UPD**: It's not about how to get var offset, the question **is how to handle the error** ?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting `((nowTimeInterval - calculatedTimeInterval) * increasePerInterval)` as a UInt32?

Comment: it's not about how to get var offset, the question is how to handle the error

Comment: You should make your question more clear. It's really hard to understand what your actual problem is. For example, "handling the error" could be as simple has printing it out, so I doubt that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow in integer arithmetic does not `throw` an error, therefore you cannot `catch` it. If you
want to detect and handle overflow, you can use one of the `...WithOverflow`
methods of the integer types. Example:

```
let a = UInt32.max
let b = UInt32(2)

if case let (result, overflow) = UInt32.multiplyWithOverflow(a, b), !overflow {
    print(result)
} else {
    print("overflow")
}
```

Comment: How about Double type?

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin: If floating point multiplication overflows then the result is "inf", so you can check with `if result.isFinite`